# Unable to minify Jekyll javascript via jekyll-assets or jekyll-minifier

Tags: jekyll

I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how to get Jekyll (v4.0.0) to minify javascript. I have installed jekyll-assets (v3.0.12) and jekyll-minifier (v0.1.10) in an effort to do so, but no luck so far... the javascript remains unminified.

I've tried a number of configuration options in _config.yml that didn't help, referencing the documentation here:

https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-assets/tree/v3.0-current#configuration

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Gemfile**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

git_source(:github) {|repo_name| "https://github.com/#{repo_name}" }

# gem "rails"

gem "jekyll", "~> 4.0"

group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-assets"
  gem "jekyll-minifier"
end
```

**_config.yml**

```
permalink: pretty

sass:
  style: compressed

exclude:
  - gulpfile.js
  - node_modules
  - CNAME
  - README
  - '*.json'
  - .DS_Store

plugins:
  - jekyll-assets
  - jekyll-minifier

assets:
  sources:
    - "css"
    - "js"
```

**_includes/scripts.html**

```
...
{% javascript app %}
...
```

**js/app.js**

```
//=require scripts.js
//=require scripts-2.js

var myStr = "app";
myStr += " js";
console.log(myStr);
```

**command line**

```
JEKYLL_ENV=production bundle exec jekyll build
```

Answer (score 0):

The Jekyll-Minifier plugin may be minifying javascript in the _site directory after Jekyll creates the static site. If you are using github pages, this won't work as Github is building from the source and has limited plugin support. You may have to build using the plugin and use the _site directory to serve manually, or find a different plugin that minimizes in place rather than in the _site directory.